# Loop through an array that is created in an it block

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a code where my `it` block generates an array, and I like to loop through it and do some tests in the same describe block. I tried writing that array to a file and access it, but those tests executes first before I write to it. I can't access `a` outside mocha tests, but I like to know whether there is anyway to do it?

```
it("test",function(done){
  a=[1,2,3]
})

a.forEach(function(i){
  it("test1",function(done){
   console.log(i)      
  })
})
```

Comment: you are trying to access a variable out of scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x = [];
describe("hello",function () {

it("hello1",function(done){
    x = [1,2,3];
    describe("hello2",function () {
        x.forEach(function(y) {       
            it("hello2"+y, function (done) {
                console.log("the number is " + y)
                done()
            })
        })
    })
    done()
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this work?

```
it("test",function(done){
    a=[1,2,3]
    a.forEach(function(i){
        it("test1",function(done){
        console.log(i)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
describe("My describe", function() {
    let a;

    it("test1", function() {
        a = [1, 2, 3];
    });

    a.forEach(function(i) {
        it("test" + i, function() {
            console.log(i);
        });
    });
});
```

If your tests are asynchronous, you will need to add the `done` callback to them. But for this simple example using `console.log()`, it is not necessary.

--EDIT--

I think the answer is "no, you can't do this". I added some `console.log` statements to see what was happening:

```
describe("My describe", function() {
    let a = [1, 2];

    it("First test", function() {
        console.log('First test');
        a = [1, 2, 3];
    });

    a.forEach(function(i) {
        console.log(`forEach ${i}`);
        it("Dynamic test " + i, function() {
            console.log(`Dynamic test ${i}`);
        });
    });
});
```

And this was the output:

```
$ mocha
forEach 1
forEach 2


  My describe
First test
    ✓ First test
Dynamic test 1
    ✓ Dynamic test 1
Dynamic test 2
    ✓ Dynamic test 2


  3 passing (7ms)
```

So, `mocha` is running the entire `describe` block and creating the dynamic tests before running any of the `it` blocks. I don't see how you would be able to generate more dynamic tests from inside an `it` block, after the tests have started.

Does your array creation have to be inside an `it` block?

Comment: Cant access "a" outside of it() block even though declared under describe()

Comment: See my edit above. Unfortunately, unless you can create your array outside of an `it` block, I think you're stuck...

Comment: i have a testcase where the "a" gets generated dynamically from a function inside a it block and i wanna loop through that and create next tests